# Embed an iFrame through Rich Text Content

Tags: richtextarea, iframe

I have a custom object with a custom field as Rich Text format.  I have an iframe I need to have inserted that will display on the front end.  Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe tag is not one of the [supported HTML tags and attributes](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_using_html_editor.htm&language=en_US) available in a rich text field. You could use a image or use a [iframe via a visual force page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_iframe.htm).

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have an iframe inserted into a rich text field. 
Even if you had the possibility to edit HTML (which is not possible) I don't believe it would very secure to do so.